# Correctly using setDefaultConfiguration() in realm

Tags: android, realm

Currently, I am setting default configuration inside the `onCreate()` method in application class.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks());
}
```

and making realm object using `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` from both activity and service. But sometimes I get this exception in my production builds.

```
Encrypted interprocess sharing is currently unsupported in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp line 113
```

The strange part is neither service nor the activity is a separate process. Though I am not been able to reproduce the issue in any of the devices I have, I am hoping that if set `RealmConfiguration` individually for each activity and service it would solve my problem.

Comment: What kind of Service are you using?

Comment: Sorry I was imprecise in my question. What implementation of the `Service` interface are you using?

Comment: I don't know what you mean all I am using is a STICKY [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService).

Comment: It looks like you're facing this issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2762

Feel free to join the discussion as it might help us to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I only opened that bug. I just want to need opinions from SO community.